# Axios api call - Failed to load ,Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Is there any reason why the code below works fine when I run it in Nodejs, using AdonisJs framework on port 3333. 
But if I run this from my React app on port 3000 in componentWillMount, I get the error

```
Failed to load https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)


 componentWillMount(){
  axios.get("https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl", {headers: {"X-Api-Key": "xxx"}})
        .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

  }
```

Comment: can you api code also?

Comment: I can private message you it, I dont want it posted here because of api limit possibility

Answer (score 1):

Preflight request is request sent by browser [for implementing CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

NodeJS just doesn't make preflight requests because it does not need to implement CORS.

Preflight request is OPTIONS request(so not response body is expected), also redirects are not allowed.

To fix this you need to configure API side properly so it does not return redirect for OPTIONS requests.

[UPD] if you cannot touch API server you may implement your own backend proxy that would take request from your frontend and ask API server internally. There will be no CORS applied(with its restrictions for preflight), also your API key will be kept in secret

Comment: I dont have access to the API side. I read up a bit, but still a little confused. The way I understand it, its so that Im not able to directly delete or update the api from my side. Is there another way to fix this, even if just on the development side for now?

Comment: @born2gamble yes, you can ask your own BE and it will send request to API server(without any CORS preflight). Also it means you will not expose you API key

Comment: Same issue I'm also facing, things are working fine with jquery request but I use axios cors error shows up.

Comment: @BijitashyaBirinchi I guess you've configured `axios` to send extra headers(authorization?) that was not done to `jquery` version

Comment: @skyboyer`axios
      .post('https://test.pvi.com/j_spring_security_check', {
        withCredentials: true,
        crossorigin: true,
        headers: {
          common: {
            'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'origin, x-requested-with',
            // 'Origin': 'https://localhost:5000',
            'X-Api-Key': 'xxx'
          }
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
          j_username: email,
          j_password: password
        })
      })`

Comment: this is my req config, tired it without the headers to avoid the options req, but no luck

Comment: better ask this as a separate question